# jQuery: Include all TRs except those that contain TH

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get a list of all TRs that do not include THs.

My initial selector is

```
$(".lanes tr")
```

I have attempted to qualify this using a `not` selector but it's not quite working

```
var rowsToInclude = $(".lanes tr").not(function(){
    return ($(this).find('th').length == 0) ? false : true;
});
```

Do I have the syntax wrong or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a `:not()` selector, but the `.not()` method. By actually using the selector, it's much simpler:

```
$(".lanes tr:not(:has(th))")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little neater and should work:

```
var rowsToInclude = $(".lanes tr").filter(function(){
    return $("th",this).length == 0
});
```

Comment: A little neater, but I think entirely the opposite of what he wants. If the length is zero you need to return false, so `.not()` doesn't exclude the element. However, given that `0` is "falsey" in Javascript, you should be able to just do `return !$('th', this).length;`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It's not the opposite in result, as I've used `.filter()` instead of `.not()`. I didn't like how the original was essentially "if not not not".
But yeah, you could happily skip the `== 0`

Comment: In that case, absolutely correct. I missed that you'd changed `.not()` to `.filter()`.